# How to read array from mongoDB document in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, mongodb, arraylist

When I try to put this `type1` array from mongoDB document , I can take that as an array through java by doing code like :

```
BasicDBList listEditionsAssets = (BasicDBList) nextAssets.get("areas");
```

following is `type1` array :

```
{
 "ClientId" : "212",
 "UserId" :"212",
 "areas" : [
   {
     "Area 1" : "Chicago"
     "Area 2" : "LA",
     "Area 3" : "Boston" 
  ]
}
```

But,following is the data I have in mongoDB document :

following is 'type2' array :

```
{
 "ClientId" : "212",
 "UserId" :"212",
 "areas" : ["Chicago","LA","Boston" ]
}
```

When I try to retrieve "areas" array in java by using BasicDBList, it comes as "null". Because java is taking it as String. When I take it as

```
BasicDBObject result = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
String areas = (String) result.get("areas");
```

I can read is as String.

So how can I read "areas" in type2  document as an Array in java and not the String ?

Comment: Are you sure `type2.areas` is an array? I've tested on my local with `mongo-java-driver 3.4.2`. It does return a list with `(List) dbObject.get("areas")`

Comment: My object -> `{ "areas" : ["1", "2"] }` and the result of above get with list casting -> `["1", "2"]`

Comment: Hi, I am getting List as "null". I tried to take it as String and it shows the result..                                                                                                                        BasicDBObject result = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
String areas = (result.getString("areas"));
System.out.println(areas);                                                                                   Can't guess why getting the List null...can you please suggest have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The only significant difference between reading an array and reading a document is that, since the elements of an array do not have names, there is no field name to read, only a series of values:

```
reader.readStartArray();

while (reader.readBsonType() != BsonType.END_OF_DOCUMENT) {
    switch (reader.getCurrentBsonType()) {
        case INT32:
            int intValue = reader.readInt32();
            break;
        case INT64:
            long longValue = reader.readInt64();
            break;
        // ... handle each supported field type
    }
}

reader.readEndArray();
```